# ASP.NET - is there a way to hold HttpContext connected after the ProcessRequest function finished?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a server side proxy that uses thread pool,
I would like to hold each HttpContext from the ProcessRequest on the same thread and only in this thread, whenever the ProcessRequest method finish its work the recieved HttpContext doesn't work anymore(my guess is that it disconnects whenever the ProcessRequest method is done)
is there anyway around it to keep the HttpContext working even when the ProcessRequest method is done?

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the underlying goal of the server side proxy?

Comment: to be able to handle 1000+ concurrent sessions.. the easy and CPU consuming solution is to open a thread for each session.. I am looking into a way to save the sessions in a side thread and work with the .net threadpool(so that i will have control over the number of open threads)

Comment: The ASP.NET framework already uses the threadpool for requests, so it's advised not to use it. See http://madskristensen.net/post/Don%E2%80%99t-use-the-ThreadPool-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A more common solution that sounds easier is to save the state somewhere instead, in the cache or database if you have the possibility to do that.

Comment: it depends on your scenario. Can you give some more information about your solution and what you are trying to solve. Do you have any code that you are using at the moment that you can post in your question?